# PureOSL Luks no longer accepts password

Tags: password, encryption, luks, bios, pureos

I need help with luks not recognizing my password all of a sudden.

I'm using pureos on a librem and I was having trouble getting wine32 installed so one of the things I did was add the debain main and contrib repos. I then ran apt-get upgrade and it upgraded a bunch of stuff. While upgrading it asked if I wanted to use my own config or the default config for some package from a pureos repo and I said use the default. Then the terminal loaded into that grey gui window and asked a similar question. I noticed the default spot for the cursor started on to select an option was the "use your own config" option so I selected that not wanting to do something weird.

Eventually I got wine working and rebooted. As I expected I had some trouble with the computer failing an HOTP/TOTP check on start up, this happens sometimes after upgrading. I got those checks sorted out with my flashdrive key. Then the luks screen loaded but now it looks different then before. Instead on having a small window with an entry field there's no window and just a line of text that says to enter my password. When I enter my luks password it always fails. I have no idea what's happening, anyone have ideas?

edit: it might also be useful to note that I ended up using aptitude to install wine32 with the upgraded packages as apt wasn't cutting it

Comment: What’s happening is that you replaced (at least parts of) PureOS with Debian... What keyboard layout do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used qwerty, which other layouts should I try? So far I tried typing it like azerty with no success, and I have no y's or z's in my password so its not qwertz(I do have some ,'. which I'm not sure if I'm typing right). Also, when I use the recovery shell, it seems like my keyboard is still qwerty. Is that shell disconnected from luks somehow?

Comment: I wondered if your layout might be have changed, but if you’re using QWERTY that won’t be the issue.

Comment: when the luks screen is loading one of the lines that comes up is          kexec -1 /boot/umlinuz[spelling]-4.19.0-5-amd64 --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-5-amd64 --append="root=UUID=[theres a uuid here]? ro quiet splash intel_iommu[spelling]=on "          The UUID displayed here is different from the UUID shown on the splash, is this a problem/could I be entering my passphrase to the wrong UUID?